# How Prometheus can scrape multiple hosts behind the service/Load balancer in Kubernetes?

Tags: prometheus

Assume I have a web service A which exposes the Prometheus metrics at /metrics . This service is deployed under the service B. Service A is deployed on three pods. How I can **scrape** the metrics from all the three pods?

Comment: FYI it’s __scrape__ (and __scraper__, __scraping__, __scraped__) not scrap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a look at the [kubernetes_sd_config](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#kubernetes_sd_config) configuration option.

This way, your prometheus server will autodiscover all the pod from your cluster. Thus, you won't need to change your configuration each time you add or remove a replica.